# Does anyone remember this Easter-related animated film?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

My wife describes watching an animated film or show when she was a child in the late 1980s/early 1990s that took place at the White House Easter egg hunt.

The only thing she remembers is that it involved a squirrel who was being given pills out of a human-sized bottle of pills by other animals, which made the squirrel hyper.  The animals giving out the pills may have been members of some kind of gang, who may have been trying to steal the eggs from the White House, and they may have been using the squirrel as some type of scout and paying him in pills (my wife isn't sure if she actually remembers those details or added them in later).  Anyone remember an animated movie or television show that included those elements?

Comment: sounds a bit like Over the Hedge - but that movie wasn't all that long ago

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ji6DDFSuabo maybe?

Comment: My wife was born in 1984, and Over the Hedge was released in 2006, so she wouldn't have been young enough when that film came out for it to be the one.  (Also we've both seen Over the Hedge, and it doesn't have any Easter-related themes that I can recall.)  Thanks!